# Analyzing geolocation and time of purchase data to determine the spatial provision strategy for a new product

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, clustering, spatial, spatio-temporal

I have a dataset containing geolocation and time of purchase information for buyers of a new product (Product X). I'd like to determine the unit of spatial provision when this product was offered to customers. In other words, I want to find out whether:

- The product was provided to all potential customers at once,
- The product was rolled out in a staggered manner at the city level,
- The product was rolled out in a staggered manner at the neighborhood level,
- The product was rolled out in a staggered manner at the postal district level

How can I provide evidence or statistically analyze this data to determine which of these cases is more likely? Are there any specific methods or tests that I should consider using for this purpose? Any guidance on approaching this problem would be greatly appreciated!